# Cannot Extend Widget Block Class

Tags: magento2, blocks, widgets, di

I have installed the Amasty ShopBy Extension and am trying to make my own modifications the correct way: using my own extension.

I have created a preference in di.xml (tried in `/etc` and `/etc/frontend`) as follows:

```
<preference for="Amasty\ShopbyBrand\Block\Widget\BrandList" type="Wildcard\AmastyShopbyExtension\Block\Widget\BrandList" />
```

And the widget block file:

```
<?php

namespace Wildcard\AmastyShopbyExtension\Block\Widget;

use Amasty\ShopbyBrand\Block\Widget\BrandList as AmastyBrandList;

class BrandList extends AmastyBrandList
{

}
```

With the above in place, the widget does not show anything at all. However, if I place a `die('here');` right before the class declaration, the word 'here' is printed. This tells me that the preference is working as it should.

Surely if I have an empty class and am extending from another, the properties and methods from the other class would all still be in tact and apply?

Also, if I add the following in my class:

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    echo "This works";

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

The 'This works' string is echoed to screen.

Is there anything I am missing?

**Using Magento 2.1.7**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forget about template. Check out

> Amasty/ShopbyBrand/view/frontend/layout directory.

You need to make sure template path contains **Amasty_ShopbyBrand** prefix.
To fix template path you can overwrite **$_template** variable in your own block or copy template file to your module.

Comment: There isn't anything in the `Amasty/ShopbyBrand/view/frontend/layout` directory... The only XML file that brings in the block is `etc/widgets.xml`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know this plugin very well, but just want to say it could be an issue with template path. you can find this path in layout xml or check out Amasty\ShopbyBrand\Block\Widget\BrandList class.

Comment: Sorry, I can't take anything from this answer to help me out. Appreciate the response, though